# How to clone a Azure Dev Ops repo from node.js package.json file?

Tags: node.js, git, azure, azure-devops, package.json

I made a repo in Azure dev ops (like a Utils thing), and I have another main project in Azure dev ops. I want to load the Utils project into my main repo using the package.json dependency list. I tried making the azure Utils repo public, or copying the clone HTTPS link, the SSH link and putting in my package.json like so

```
  "dependencies": {
    "webapputils":"git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/GlobalApps/WebAppUtils/WebAppUtils"
  },
```

This one at least didn't throw an error, but it only creates a shortcut folder in the generated node_modules folder. If I try to open it, it says it can't be found.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Please use [git sub modules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) for this, like:

```
git submodule add https://GlobalApps@dev.azure.com/GlobalApps/WebAppUtils/WebAppUtils
```

See the [docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) or Marco's blog for more explanation:
https://blog.olandese.nl/2019/07/14/using-git-submodules-in-private-azure-devops-repositories/

Comment: I misunderstood the question, sorry, but I repacked and rewritten my answer ;-)